# Crashlytics upload dSYM manually for obfuscated application

Tags: ios, firebase, obfuscation, crashlytics, ixguard

I've integrated crashlytics in an application that uses ixguard as obfuscation tool. Making the suggested tests using simulator on non obfuscated version works fine.
To de-symbolicate correctly obfuscated app crash logs a different dSYM file is required. This new dSYM is provided by the obfuscation tool and I upload it using firebase portal.
In the firebase console I can see some crashlogs that I generated by making the app crash, but they still require the correct dSYM (Required). It seems that the new dSYM is not taken into account.
By running `dwarfdump -u Obfuscated.BS.dSYM` I can clearly see that the required UUID is present in the list so they should match.
My concern is that at build time Fabric runs a script that should upload automatically the dSYM on Fabric portal, I'm wondering if this double upload could break something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I’ve found the issue, this is probably due to the generated dSYM by iXguard because it has a different structure from the one generate by Xcode.
Inside the dSYM folder of the archive you’ll find something like that:

```
dSYM
    |
    |->ThirdPartyLib1.dSYM
    |->ThirdPartyLib2.dSYM
    |->MyApp.dSYM
    |->ThirdPartyLib3.dSYM
```

MyApp.dSYM is structured like this

```
MyApp.dSYM
        |
        |->Contents
                |
                |->Info.plist
                |->Resources
                        |
                        |->DWARF
                                |
                                |->MyApp
```

The one from iXguard is kind of mixed up:

```
MyApp.dSYM
        |
        |->Contents
                |
                |->Info.plist
                |->Resources
                        |
                        |->DWARF
                                |
                                |->MyApp
                                |->ThirdPartyLib1
                                |->ThirdPartyLib2
                                |->ThirdPartyLib3
```

If I upload the iXguard file Crashlytics doesn’t recognize it as valid, if I modify it maintaining the original structure it works.

Problem solved.

I hope this could help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric and Firebase here. We don't have support for iXGuard. Uploading dSYMs after they're missing won't cause any problems. My hunch is that iXGuard is doing something that we're not expecting as we don't have support on it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution and information you found!